# Image size in DefaultPredictor of Detectron2

Tags: pytorch, detectron

For object detection, I'm using detectron2.
I want to fix the input image size so I made my customized dataloader:

```
def build_train_loader(cls, cfg):
    dataloader = build_detection_train_loader(cfg,
        mapper=DatasetMapper(cfg, is_train=True, augmentations=[
            T.Resize((1200, 1200))
        ]))
```

What I wonder is for the prediction, I can use the *DefaultPredictor* of detectron2 and resize my images to (1200, 1200) as prepossessing before sending to the predictor?
Or the DefaultPredictor is resizing the image before the prediction and I have to override a function to resize to (1200, 1200)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to preprocess the images yourself or to write your own predictor that will apply the resize before calling the model.

The [DefaultPredictor](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/1f522c1b45b0c3192402ed5c4ae03170eed65590/detectron2/engine/defaults.py#L188) applies a [ResizeShortestEdge](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/1f522c1b45b0c3192402ed5c4ae03170eed65590/detectron2/engine/defaults.py#L224) transform (that can be configured in the config file), but this is not exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I am also aware of the ResizeShortestEdge function and the INPUT.MIN_SIZE_{TRAIN, TEST} configurations.
Do you think I have to modify them also to make sure about the input size of the network?

Comment: Also, I don’t understand with ResizeShortestEdge how the input images can be in different sizes and not square-shaped?

Comment: Yes you have to modify INPUT.MIN_SIZE_{TRAIN, TEST} to ensure the input size will be what you want.

Comment: ResizeShortestEdge will increase the size until the shortest edge reaches the given value, and such that the original image ratio is preserved. Then if the longest edge has become larger than the given limit, it will reduce the image to fit the requirements.

I would advice writting your own predictor that uses the Resize transform.

Comment: @RémiChauvenne , I have a simple question: what does edge mean in this context? Could you please help me with this matter?

Comment: In this context, the shortest edge is min(height, width) of the image